# How to adjust the table view cell padding?

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, uicollectionview, padding

When I design a custom table view cell composed of 2 labels and a collection view, I find the distance between cell content and the bottom side is too large and try to reduce the height of the cell. But the content is overlapped with something I don't know what it is, as you can see from pictures:

[image: original]  =>  [image: lower height cell]

I add green border to the area to make it clear.
How to adjust this padding like area to place cell content nearer to the bottom?

UPDATE: This issue is resolved by letting the bottom border of the collection view always overlap with the bottom border of the table view cell. Is it required when design table view cell?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you change the size of the custom cell, make sure you also change the **Cell size** property of the UITableView. You cand do this from the .nib (if you are using) or programmatically with:

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    return height-of-custom-cell;
}
```